# trigger function error in postgres, said that column doesn't exists when it actualy exists

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I'm trying to implement full text search and have successfully created a trigger function

```
CREATE FUNCTION content_vector_generate() RETURNS trigger AS $$
begin
    new.content_vector := 
        to_tsvector('simple', coalesce("title" ,'') || ' ' || coalesce("content" ,''));
    return new;
    end
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
     
CREATE TRIGGER content_vector_generate BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
        ON "Posts" FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE content_vector_generate();
```

but when i try, to check the function work properly by inserting / updating row

```
INSERT INTO public."Posts"(id,title,content)
VALUES(1,'post-title','etc-content')
```

i got this error instead

```
SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "title" does not exist
  Where: PL/pgSQL function content_vector_generate() line 3 at assignment
```

do I have wrong syntax, i've tried removed the quotation mark too

Comment: You need to reference the column in the `NEW` record: `new.title`  and `new.content`. Additionally: string constants need to be enclosed in single quotes so your insert needs to be `VALUES(1,'post-title','etc-content')`

Comment: thankyou now it works properly

Answer (score 1):

as [@a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name) mention i need to reference the column new row in the function like :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION content_vector_generate() RETURNS trigger AS $$
begin
    new.content_vector := 
        to_tsvector('simple', coalesce(new."title" ,'') || ' ' || coalesce(new."content" ,''));
    return new;
    end
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```